# Removing html input array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Take the following code for example:

```
<div id="instructor_trainers">    

    <div id="trainer-1" class="trainer-group form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="trainers[1][trainer]" name="trainers[1][trainer]">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="trainer-expiration form-control" placeholder="Expiration" id="trainers[1][expiration]" name="trainers[1][expiration]" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="trainer-comments form-control" placeholder="Comments" id="trainers[1][comments]" name="trainers[1][comments]"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="trainer-2" class="trainer-group form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="trainers[2][trainer]" name="trainers[2][trainer]">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="trainer-expiration form-control" placeholder="Expiration" id="trainers[2][expiration]" name="trainers[2][expiration]" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="trainer-comments form-control" placeholder="Comments" id="trainers[2][comments]" name="trainers[2][comments]"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="trainer-3" class="trainer-group form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="trainers[3][trainer]" name="trainers[3][trainer]">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="trainer-expiration form-control" placeholder="Expiration" id="trainers[3][expiration]" name="trainers[3][expiration]" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="trainer-comments form-control" placeholder="Comments" id="trainers[3][comments]" name="trainers[3][comments]"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Each trainer element inside of div `instructor_trainers` consists of three input fields, which are all contained inside of a `trainers` array. Whenever a new element is created, the index is found by incrementing the existing number of elements by one. When an element is removed, this value is decremented by one, and elements are only able to be removed in the order they were added (so if I were to click on my remove button trainer-3 would be removed, then trainer-2, and finally trainer-1).

Is there a way to update the array indexes automatically if an element is removed out of order. For example, if I changed my remove function to remove a specific id (such as trainer-2) is there a way to shift the index values of all elements after the removed element? So if `trainer-2` is removed, then the three inputs in `trainer-3` would have their index values shifted to 2?

This could be done by rebuilding each element after the deleted element, but it just feels like I'm missing something, like there's an easier way to go about it.

Comment: no. they'd have to be updated via code. the... "easier" way would be to use a framework that abstracts that work away from you. like react or angular.

Comment: i recommend knockout ;-)  http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html

Comment: how about vue.js? As it appears to be what's integrated with laravel now.

Comment: dunno, never worked with it. If it maintains the view for you based on a set of data and updates when the data changes, that'd likely solve your problem.

Comment: @KevinB greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you add and remove elements?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being until I familiarize myself with vue.js or react.js frontend frameworks, I am calling the following function which re-indexes all of the elements:

```
function reindexTrainerElements(){

    $(".trainer-group").each(function(index) {

        var prefix = "trainers[" + index + "]";
        $(this).find("select").each(function() {
            this.id = this.id.replace(/trainers\[\d+\]/, prefix);
            this.name = this.name.replace(/trainers\[\d+\]/, prefix);
        });
        $(this).find("input").each(function() {
            this.id = this.id.replace(/trainers\[\d+\]/, prefix);
            this.name = this.name.replace(/trainers\[\d+\]/, prefix);
        });
        $(this).find("textarea").each(function() {
            this.id = this.id.replace(/trainers\[\d+\]/, prefix);
            this.name = this.name.replace(/trainers\[\d+\]/, prefix);
        });

    });

}
```

This is a variation of Shawns answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370317/re-numbering-text-input-array-indices-with-jquery)